# Including root access within shell script

Tags: shell

I need to include sudo su - within the shell script and execute the remaining part of the shell script. i need a workaround to do this as i want root permission to execute remaining part of the script . can anyone help me in achieving this?

Comment: Can't you just execute the script as sudo?

Comment: actually the requirement of the client is such that everything including root access has to be automated within the srcipt itself. can someone please suggest something on these lines

Comment: i have actually been able to run script as sudo sh ./script.sh successfully.but as the client doesnt want this, i had to abandon this.

Comment: you can divide your code in 2 shell scripts the portion which needs to be executed as root keep in some other shell file and invoke it from parent script using sudo sh